# java.sql.SQLException: not found - JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I keep getting the following error when running my code: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'Hours Worked' not found.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong, I apologize if it is obvious, I'm still trying to learn how to properly use JDBC.

Here is where i think the error is in my code:

```
String sql = "SELECT jobID, 'Hours'+'/'+'Worked', Description, Address, 'Materials'+'/'+'Used', Seen FROM main";
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          //Extract data from result set
          while(rs.next()){
             //Retrieve by column name
             int id  = rs.getInt("JobID");
             int Hrs = rs.getInt("Hours Worked");
             String description = rs.getString("Description");
             String Address = rs.getString("Address");
             String Materials = rs.getString("Materials Used");
             String Seen = rs.getString("Seen");

             //Display values
             System.out.print("JobID: " + id);
             System.out.print(", Hours Worked: " + Hrs);
             System.out.print(", Description: " + description);
             System.out.println(", Address: " + Address);
             System.out.println(", Materials Used: " + Materials);
             System.out.println(", Seen: " + Seen);
          }
```

Comment: `int hours = rs.getInt("Hours/Worked");`....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must wrap the columns names with whitespaces in square brackets in a sql server query like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT jobID, [Hours Worked], Description, Address, [Materials Used], Seen FROM main";
```